# How to save deep learning Ann model in through pipeline

Tags: deep-learning, pickle, h5py

Am try to dump in pickle but that not work.[image: I got this error in pickle file] ,

Got Error in load pickle with pipeline Steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its python versioning issue in windows.
Try to run in Linux & use python stable version.
thx...